# Unable to submit when using a tag reserved for moderators

Tags: feature-request

> Oops! Your question couldn't be
>   submitted because: •  'faq rules
>   stackoverflow discussion ' contains a
>   tag reserved for moderator use

User should be told which specific tag is needed to be removed to comply or, perhaps, the system should automatically remove the tag automatically. I should not have to use trial and error to solve the issue.

As a side note, the offending tag was FAQ which seems rather odd since this would be the site SO would send people to talk about the FAQ.

Comment: The `[faq]` tag is for questions that are part of the official Stack Overflow FAQ, and is thus reserved for moderator use only. To discuss things, the `[discussion]` tag should suffice.

Comment: While I understand why, it seems odd to me to that the burden of specialized knowledge of reserved tags is placed on the user rather then the moderators. Perhaps Mod tags would be better impliemented with a prefix? Perhaps, the FAQ tag is exception to the rule. I certainly hope that most intuitive tags are not reserved.